# Recommendations for books on partial differential equations, with lots of examples and generally focusing on solutions?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reference-request

This semester, I am taking a partial differential equations course for the first time. What are your book recommendations with lots of examples and generally focusing on solutions? Especially for an undergraduate student taking this course for the first time?

Comment: When I first took PDE as an undergraduate student, the book used was *Partial Differential Equations: An Introduction*, by Walter A. Strauss. Maybe it's worth it to check it out.

Comment: What do you mean by “generally focusing on solutions”? The whole subject is about solutions (to PDEs).

Comment: It is a book with plenty of examples, usually in the form of questions and solutions. @HansLundmark